# RegisterResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Using new android studio with new 3.0.0 Gradle pluging.
When building some warning happened:

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
```

Comment: can you show your gradle tasks? do u have apk splits?

Comment: please show your Gradle

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10629) describing the exact problem (a known issue) and a workaround?  (First hit on Google.)

Comment: @ashleedawg what should I do? update android studio? or some libraries?

Comment: @ashleedawg the workaround you mention is, unless I misunderstand it, to stay with older version of gradle plugin. This is not a way to handle deprecation in the long run. In the short run, the warning can be <s>ignored</s> remembered, but no immediate action needed.

Answer (score 47):

From what I can tell, plugins added as classpath dependencies will give problems. I.e. [Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/271) had an issue with it. [Spoon](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin/issues/155) and [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13492/commits/09e4fd275b0770d9fd922b57585a107bbc101411) as well. Doing [this Google search](https://www.google.no/search?q=registerResGeneratingTask+is+deprecated) reveals a lot of GitHub repos with an issue raised over the same thing, and all they have in common is the fact that it's a Gradle plugin. Fabric appears to be a cause as well, as mentioned by [Mate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281743/6296561)*

From what I can tell, the issue comes from a/multiple Gradle plugin (s). It can also be triggered by your Gradle code, but this is most likely not applicable if your project is an app and not a Gradle plugin.

And as mentioned by [Alex Cohn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984770/registerresgeneratingtask-is-deprecated-use-registergeneratedfoldersfilecollec#comment82033745_46984770) in a comment, deprecation is a warning. In this case, it means it's a feature that's going to be removed eventually. So for now, assuming it is a plugin (and not made by you), you can ignore it. By the time it's removed, most/all of the major plugins should be updated to fix it.

And, again, **it is a warning;** not an error. You can still run it, and ignore it if there's nothing you can do about the issue. Disabling e.g. the Fabric* plugin is overkill, as it still works.

<sub>I don't use Fabric myself, and Fabric isn't open-source, so I don't know if the developers fixed it or not</sub>

**TL;DR:** Gradle plugins are the cause. It's a warning (not an error), so removing the plugins that cause the issue is overkill. If you can't fix it, leave it alone as long as it is only deprecated at the moment (not removed)

---

If you use Firebase, there is a specific solution to it that's also mentioned in the migration guide (linked later in this post); exclude the guava module

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

---

The issue itself is fairly hard to detect. From what I can tell, there is no single issue that causes it in all of the plugins I checked (and linked in this answer). If you have coded something that causes the issue (and it's possible to fix it; adding a 3rd party gradle plugin isn't causing it), there are some things you can try to fix it.

From what I can tell as of the actual cause, it's solved by updating the Gradle file (though in the Spoon library, it was fixed by changing a line related to `TestVariant`) by following the topics in the Gradle plugin 3.0.0 migration guide.

The entire thing is covered [by the developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html), but here's some of the stuff I think is relevant based on the pull requests done on projects where it's been a problem:

Aside updating the Gradle version and plugin, you also need to add the `google()` repo under `repositories`.

`compile` is now `implementation` or `api`, but `implementation` is the recommended one.

`provided` is `compileOnly` and `apk` is `runtimeOnly`

`androidTestCompile` has become `androidTestImplementation`, and `testCompile` -> `testImplementation`

If you use flavors, you have to use flavor dimensions (covered by the docs).

For build types, you have to include fallbacks in case there is a library that doesn't have that build type. These are defined in the `profile` block under the `android` block.

If not done already, the gradle plugin has to be defined first. If you don't have any other classpath dependencies, it isn't a problem. But if you do, make sure the gradle plugin is defined first.

If you use `testVariants`, make sure you don't call `testedVariant` in the class. It appears to be the cause for the Spoon library.

These things are, from what I have been able to tell, some of the changes that were made to fix the issue.

Comment: But I am not able to debug code line it shows error

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
29 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 27 up-to-date

Comment: @AbhinavGupta that's not the stacktrace. That's just a message telling you something went wrong

Comment: but I am not able to solve this and cause of this i am not able to install apk in my device

Comment: @AbhinavGupta so ask a new question on Stack Overflow

Comment: Looks like this is in the queue to get fixed soon...  https://github.com/fossasia/open-event-orga-app/pull/1591

Answer (score 18):

I am using the Play services Gradle plugin `com.google.gms:google-services` with version `4.2.0`.

In the source code we can see that:
[image]

So for me, that was the reason of my warnings and cannot be removed until the plugin gets fixed. The issue is [here](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/23)

As mentioned by @Zoe, this may come from other Gradle Plugins also.

Answer (score 18):

The issue is resolved with Google Services Plugin Version 4.3.0 (Resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/commit/4b805592ac337721b58f51cd3696306e2b45043c))

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Change version to 4.3.0
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845863/2213898)

Answer (score 10):

Updating to the latest version of the Fabric Gradle Plugin fixes this issue.

From the changelog:

- Fixed “registerResGeneratingTask” deprecation warning.

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#march-15-2018

Comment: What is it exactly though? Is it worth upgrading ? Does it cause any issues (before and after update) ? We use v2.6.8 and now they have v2.9.3 , but I don't see how to look at it in the changelog. They have different versions there ("1.4.2 May 24, 2018" for example)

Comment: @androiddeveloper You're confusing Fabric Gradle Plugin and Crashlytics. Check out different components in the left menu.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was caused by mismatched version of the Android support libraries.
I updated all modules to the latest version (28.0.0) and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Fabric properly this issue got solved for me

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class MyApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message and lot of others like

`x-version is deprecated and use y-version instead and it'll be removed in 2019`

and all of my project started giving same error messages suddenly.

Android studio was giving warnings about my antivirus program. I tried configuring it but didn't work.

Finally **I uninstalled QuickHeal antivirus from my system** and all is well now

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are about problems with *third-party components*.

Here's how to update *your* project that uses `registerResGeneratingTask` directly:

Before:

```
variant.registerResGeneratingTask generateIcon, ICON_DIR
```

After:

```
variant.mergeResourcesProvider.get().dependsOn generateIcon
variant.registerGeneratedResFolders files(ICON_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Project Level Build.Gradle

Use following version of google services dependency.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
}
```

Solved issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

For me this warning disappeared when I turned off fabric gradle plugin, o please check if you use fabric or another plugin that i responsible for this warning.

Comment: Removed fabric, but still this warning appears.

Comment: I'm not using fabric and I have this message!

Comment: Disabling plugin io.fabric reduced 8 of these warnings to 4. So it seems there is more than one source.

Comment: `com.google.gms:google-services` `4.0.1` & `4.0.2` both cause this warning notice.