# registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem when build my app on android studio (java)

```
> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

in gradle-wrapper.properties i jave tried

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip
```

still problem exist, when create new APP i dont see this problem

classes and dependencies are updated to last versions

I tried all suggestions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984770/registerresgeneratingtask-is-deprecated-use-registergeneratedfoldersfilecollec) but no help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegisterResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984770/registerresgeneratingtask-is-deprecated-use-registergeneratedfoldersfilecollec)

Comment: Problem still exist i tried every think but no solution, anyways app if working fine even with that problem

Comment: I think this is only a warning, Wait more time than usual. However, app is working with this warning.

Answer (score 34):

The issue is resolved with Google Services Plugin Version 4.3.0 ([Resolved with this commit](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/commit/4b805592ac337721b58f51cd3696306e2b45043c))

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Change version to 4.3.0
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: But instead it rises another issue: `WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.`
https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/65

Answer (score 14):

Looks like this is solved, once and for all, without new warnings with this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-09-06)

Comment: Didnt fix the problem

Answer (score 5):

I was developing an app using Google Flutter and tried installing firebase. I was following Google's tutorial and turns out my gradle version and android studio needed an update. I was also following the google guide wrong, there's one for flutter firebase and then the other is android firebase. I went back and followed the flutter firebase guide.

So I made changes by adding the following to my project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
  }
}
```

and added this to my app-level build.gradle

```
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Made these changes using Android Studio so I can sync all the changes throughout the app and it fixed the error.

Comment: It did not solved my problem (which was exactly the same). It only raised more error while sync.

Comment: Updated to 4.3.0*

Comment: Didnt fix the problem

Comment: For me it worked. I updated project level dependencies, then changed to latest gradle, cause android studio wanted that. And after that also it showed that i needed to use latest android studio version. So i updated also that.

Answer (score 2):

In the app level build.gradle update your androidX dependencies, for me worked changing to this versions

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

My minSdkVersion is 19 so don't know if needed to update to 23 as suggested in by some people

Comment: Didnt fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' solves this issue.

And also it solves the issue:
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.

The above issue is generated when you use
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
So avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

Last version: (on feb 2021)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```