# Trouble when trying to run android project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When I try to build an Android app in react native, I always get an error. So, I ran the

`cd android && gradlew installDebug --stacktrace`

command and the output is as follows:

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from C:\Users\User\Documents\Neuron Apps\PassventApp\mg-app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\User\Documents\Neuron Apps\PassventApp\mg-app\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:375)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.access$000(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker$1.run(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:260)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:484)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$acceptOnlyOne$2(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:75)
        at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$select$3(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:100)
        at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMergerOutputs$1.create(IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java:88)
        at com.android.builder.merge.DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.create(DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.java:64)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResourcesDelegate$run$output$1.create(MergeJavaResourcesDelegate.kt:228)
        at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.updateChangedFile(IncrementalFileMerger.java:242)
        at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.mergeChangedInputs(IncrementalFileMerger.java:203)
        at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.merge(IncrementalFileMerger.java:80)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResourcesDelegate.run(MergeJavaResourcesDelegate.kt:257)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResRunnable.run(MergeJavaResRunnable.kt:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:348)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        ... 3 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
305 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 302 up-to-date
```

Can anyone tell me what can I do to solve this issue? I'm fairly new at React Native so I don't know excactly what's causing this problem in the first place.

Working in a Windows 10 machine and an Android phone.

Comment: Maybe this answer help for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125515/registerresgeneratingtask-is-deprecated-use-registergeneratedresfoldersfilecol

Answer (score 0):

in android gradle you can use pick first

```
packagingOptions {
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
   }
```