# can't resolve R.drawable.file.xml

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For 2 days ago, I got the following error:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configure project :app
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Task :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :core:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :core:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :core:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :core:processDebugManifest
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild
>   Task :core:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :core:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: /media/dr/2DD53B9005F868921/.androidProgects/answerVet/app/google-services.json
>
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :core:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :core:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :core:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :core:generateDebugResources
>   Task :core:packageDebugResources
>   Task :core:generateDebugRFile
>   Task :core:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :core:generateDebugSources
>   Task :core:javaPreCompileDebug
>
> Task :core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /media/dr/2DD53B9005F868921/.androidProgects/answerVet/core/src/main/java/com/ask/core/activities/audioDetailsActivity/AudioController.java:159: error: cannot find symbol
>           final int recordIcon =  R.drawable.ic_record_audio;
>                                             ^
>     symbol:   variable ic_record_audio
>     location: class drawable

//many lines of can't find symbol

then :

> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

In the `AudioController.java:159`, there is no error and the icon is displayed beside the line.

I had tried all the suggested answers in the similar questions:

1. clean project.
2. invalidate and restart.
3. delete build directory.
4. inspect code and correct all errors.
5. solve all errors and warning in the manifest file.

**Edit**
I am using firebase in my project. the following din't solve the proplem.

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
```

Comment: Can you open the generated R java file and check if that symbol exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegisterResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984770/registerresgeneratingtask-is-deprecated-use-registergeneratedfoldersfilecollec)

Answer (score 0):

That is how this error gone, It may help someone.

I commented all drawable that android studio complain from them.
then it starts to complain from other files.
In my case; there is style file that has malformed format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  ....  
</selector>
```

Other things I did may play a role for other cases:

1. migrate to androidx ( hard job )
2. upgrade gradle wrapper and plug in to latest Beta version.
3. for who are using firebase, adding the following lines to the `project.gradle` is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984770/registerresgeneratingtask-is-deprecated-use-registergeneratedfoldersfilecollec).

`classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }`