# Cloud firestore crashes app in APK release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, crash

Flutter Cloud Firestore is creating an error on my Flutter App, when i execute it on a APK in release mode it just crashes the app and close it. I have AndroidX and everything works fine when i try the app from flutter run --release and i have my device connected. I have this issue for a week and I haven't found a way to solve it.

First I thought it was an issue with the Google Maps Plugin but later I realize that it also happened in other parts of the app where i don't use it but where I used the cloud_firestore library too. So I think there is an issue with this

This is my console when i execute flutter build apk

```
Gabriels-MacBook-Pro:Safer jumpbotron$ flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              1.3s
Resolving dependencies...                                           4.0s
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: /Users/jumpbotron/Documents/programming/installations/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/jumpbotron/Documents/programming/installations/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: /Users/jumpbotron/Documents/programming/installations/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.3+6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/connectivity/ConnectivityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/jumpbotron/Documents/programming/installations/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.              
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
RRemoved unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 256KB to 233KB: Removed 8%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     117.5s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk (7.2MB).
```

Comment: Yes, but it is build. Can you give a stack trace?

Comment: As i told you everything works fine in debug mode, the problem comes when i make a build apk and i install it, it simply don't works

Comment: have you tried `flutter run --release`?

Comment: it works greatly with flutter run --release the problem is when i create an apk file when i execute the app from it it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following lines are pointing the issue.

```
Resolving dependencies...                                           4.0s
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
```

Deprecation is not an error, is a warning. In this case it is warning you that this feature will be removed eventually.

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/fossasia/open-event-organizer-android/issues/1547) and according to this conversation it is already [fixed](https://github.com/fossasia/open-event-organizer-android/pull/1591)

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48309373/11928130) really helpful as it explains the cause of the problem.